# JQM: Is Modern/Metro UI concept possible?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, modern-ui

It's known, that jqm works with pages, that are screen wide.

Is it possible to implement in jqm & phonegap an app, that has pages wider than the screen and lets user horizontally scroll, like it's done in MS's Modern/Metro UI?

In case of MS Dynamics, for some reason, microsoft guys using native development tools on tablets to implement this Modern/Metro UI feature. In the same time they omitting this feature in their web client. I think it's not a coincidence, but the reason behind it is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you this,

Jquery, CSS and HTM5 are very Powerfull.

check out the CSS Metro ui Streamer demo

http://metroui.org.ua/streamer.html

http://metroui.org.ua/

I presume that's something similar you are after if not the one.